# Selected or not... word automatically deleting space after sentence

Tags: vba, ms-word

Once again I have a problem of understanding the behavior of Word. What I want to do is to replace text in big word documents. Most of the VBA code is working precisely as expected… are parts are not (or at least not in my brain…).

Consider a word document with these three sentences:

This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence. This is the third sentence.

When I select the second sentence, from the capital letter T (This) to the end of the sentence including the space after the dot, and run this code

```
Sub SelectAndReplace()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myText As String
    
    Set myRange = Selection.Range
    myText = "This is the sentence in the middle."
    
    myRange.Delete
    myRange.text = myText

End Sub
```

Then I get no space between the second and third sentence (middle.This). This is logical in my mind. But I get exactly the same result if I select the second sentence without the space at the end. Word seems to decide for me that the space at the end should also be deleted. But I do not want this to happen.

When researching this I get a lot of information about the smart selecting of word. I have been tinkering with these settings but is does not have an effect when running the code. This actually makes me happy because I do not want the code to run differently on separate computers depending on these settings. A lot of other people actually are looking for solutions to get rid of extra spaces (which is making my search difficult)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Just adding an extra space at the end of my replacement text is not going to help. Sometimes the selection/range will be in the middle of a word (and then I do not want an extra space).

Thanks

Comment: When you delete the sentence without selecting the space on the end Word detects that there are two spaces together and deletes the second one. This behavior is identical to what happens when you select a sentence and hit the delete key.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Yes I know. But can I control this behavior in VBA? If not... then I will need to redesign part of my work.

Comment: Ah, I found that my problem is caused by the "Use smart cut and paste" settings. I doubt whether I can control with VBA. Back to the drawing table...

Comment: `Options.PasteAdjustWordSpacing = False`

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it! Also found it out myself :). Now answering my own question...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Timothy

```
Sub SelectAndReplace()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myText As String
    Dim beginStatusPasteAdjustWordSpacing As Boolean
    
    beginPasteAdjustWordSpacing = Options.PasteAdjustWordSpacing 'store status         
    Set myRange = Selection.Range
    myText = "This is the sentence in the middle."
    
    Options.PasteAdjustWordSpacing = False
    myRange.Delete
    myRange.text = myText
    Options.PasteAdjustWordSpacing = beginPasteAdjustWordSpacing 'set back original status

End Sub
```